# Is there a way to change television input using Qt serial port?

Tags: c++, qt, input

I was wondering if there is a way that I can use Qt to cycle between the inputs of a tv. For example, if I was playing xbox on hdmi 1, the program could switch inputs to hdmi 2 to make sure I didn't miss the show that I wanted to watch.

I know I could use a dvr and record the show and blah blah blah, but this is just an example. I already have the code that opens and closes the serial port (and yes, it needs to be done through a serial port):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSerialPort>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSerialPort serial;

    serial.setPortName("PlayerPort");
    serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);



    serial.close();

    //QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    //return a.exec();
}
```

So what I need now is the code to actually do the channel switching. If at all possible, I would like to write the code myself, so if you could point me in the right direction as far as a function library for the TV (LG brand), that would be great.

Comment: what do you want to watch?

Comment: Anything that will play through another hdmi port. So just standard cable tv works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There's a copy of an operator's manual for some models [here](http://rdex.net/projects/lg_tv/37lc7d.pdf), if you don't have your own (commands are page 88).

General format of commands is [CMD1][CMD2][DATA][CRLF]

For input select CMD1 is `x` and CMD2 is `b`.

```
To select input source for TV.
Transmission [x][b][ ][Set ID][ ][Data][Cr]
Data 00 : DTV (Antenna) 
Data 40 : Component 1
Data 01 : DTV (Cable) 
Data 41 : Component 2
Data 10 : Analog (Antenna) 
Data 60 : RGB PC
Data 11 : Analog (Cable) 
Data 90 : HDMI1/DVI
Data 20 : AV1
Data 91 : HDMI2
Data 21 : AV2
Acknowledgement [b][ ][Set ID][ ][OK/NG][Data][x]
```

A C project where you can lift code from is [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lg-tv-command/).

Comment: unfortunately, the code does not compile (yes, I made sure I had saved the file as C instead of C++), and this is because I don't have access to all of the header files used in that project. I tried pulling code from the "SendCommand" function, but it simply has too many pieces that I have no  idea what they are.

Comment: The C project is Linux code I think, if you want to compile it "as is". But you don't have to, you can use the LG doc + C code to figure out your Qt code. For instance, the `SendCommand` is where the action is, it's a `write` to the serial port, then some code to parse the TV response.